# htaccess displays error 500 when adding more than 3 rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this is my htaccess:

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^home index.php
RewriteRule  ^register register.php
RewriteRule  ^rules rules.php [L]
```

When i add fourth rule to htaccess it returns 500 error. 
so htaccess is allowing only 3 rewrite rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is when you receive an error you should always check your Apache error_log file. It will give you the specific reason for the error. We would only be guessing at what your problem might be.

Now this might not be "the" issue however the `RewriteCond` only works for the `RewriteRule` directly following it. You can't use the same condtions for all of your rules. You should also get in to the habit of using the `[L]` flag on the rules to prevent it from reading the next rule once it has matched.

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^home/?$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^register/?$ register.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^rules/?$ rules.php [L]
```

Comment: Sorry, your code didn't helped. It returns 500 anyway.

Comment: Apache logs don't have info about it. Last entries is about POST form submitting.

Comment: which log are you looking at?

Comment: Also edit your question with the exact contents of your htaccess file.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Text editor just formatted htaccess like this: http://prntscr.com/6cm669
Now fixed that! Thanks!

Comment: Glad you sort it out.